# Flutter GitHub Actions Bad CPU type in executable

Tags: flutter, dart, github-actions, apple-silicon

Hi I am currently using this [GitHub Action](https://gist.github.com/rodydavis/bde9a9a8c2fcdcf3474c0f50248f2e3a) for CI/CD for my flutter project

Which `runs-on: macOS-latest` which I assume will be apple silicon. When it runs the `flutter pub get` in `build_ios:` I get this error.

```
/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/flutter/2.13.0-0.1.pre-dev/x64/bin/internal/shared.sh: line 225: 
/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/flutter/2.13.0-0.1.pre-dev/x64/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart: Bad CPU type in executable
```

Now I think the problem may be to do with not having rosseta stone installed on the GitHub action?

Any thoughts on how to install rosseta stone, or if this is a different error?

Comment: GitHub-hosted runners are all currently x86.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you specify `architecture: arm64`

```
- uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
  with:
    flutter-version: '2.10.4'
    architecture: arm64
```

Comment: I tried adding `architecture: arm64` and installing Rosetta before the `flutter pub get` runs but nothing helps... has anyone experienced the same?

Comment: @AlexanderKrol try my solution - I was in the same situation as yourself.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer unfortunately did not work for me.

The fix for myself was the following:

```
- uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
    with:
      channel: 'stable'
      architecture: x64
```

Note that I upgraded the version of subsito from v1 to v2 and specified an architecture of x64.

Answer (score 4):

For me, the fix was to use the version 2 of [`subosito/flutter-action@v1`](https://github.com/subosito/flutter-action) instead of 1:

```yaml
- uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2 # instead of @v1
```

Answer (score 3):

**This is my solution** on a Flutter Project (Tested on Flutter 3.0.1 and Flutter 3.0.2).

My GitHub CI/Pipeline **ci.yaml**

```
- uses: actions/setup-java@v1
  with:
    java-version: "12.x"

- uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
  with:
    channel: "stable"
    flutter-version: "3.0.2"
    architecture: x64

- name: flutter doctor
  run: |
    flutter doctor -v
```

Important as [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3316737/james-mallon) mentioned: version of subsito needs to be v2 and specified an architecture of x64.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem, upgrade the `flutter-action` from v1.5.1 to v2 fixed this problem, there is no need to specify the architecture:

```
- uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1.5.1
  with:
      flutter-version: '3.0.5'
      channel: 'stable'
```